# How do I change the minimum space on a partition?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I recently got ubuntu and arch linux, ubuntu for being useful and arch linux to learn how everything works. i have an 80gb hard drive and want to seperate everything into 40gbs for ubuntu and 30 for archlinux, but when i try using gparted, the minimm and maximum spaces are exactly the same (73.54gb)

Comment: Please add a screenshot of GParted for detail information.

Comment: The minimum size is based on how much used space you already have in the partition.  In other words, you can't make it any smaller if it is 100% used.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, brand new laptop, 1tb hhd and for some reason when i installed ubuntu it decided to use the entire drive into an lvm2pv mounting on ubuntu-vg, this has 900gb partitioned to it, and will only allow me to re-size 8MiB when i need atleast 100gb to dual boot steamos.

Here are some links with pictures:

This one is on [how to setup a bootable usb/cd](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) for Ubuntu 14.04.

And one on how to [re-size your Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/) partition from the trial version of Ubuntu.

You will need the bootable usb/cd to boot from in order to access the trial version of Ubuntu.

I found something helpful online, it requires you have a usb or cd that you can write on and time.

Making sure no one skips this part:

**DO NOT UNPLUG THE USB OR EJECT THE CD, AND IF YOU CAN BACK UP YOUR MACHINE.**

^ This will make more sense as your read on. ^

## Step 1:

Plug in usb or cd, must be 4gb or larger. SD and Micro SD cards work but only with usb adapters (you can write on the by plugging them in directly but machines will only see them during boot if they are in a disk drive or usb port)

## Step 2:

Open start up disk creator

You're going to need the ubuntu 14.04 iso files which you can download from their website

## Step 3:

In start up disk creator, there should be 2 boxes

```
Box 1: Source disc image(.iso)

Box 2: Disk to use:
```

Box 1 will contain the location of the ubuntu iso you just downloaded, box 2 contains information on the usb drives or cd currently mounted. If there is anything on the usb device or cd, back it up and erase the disk.

After the disk has been erased, make sure that the iso and the disk you want to convert into a start up drive are highlighted. Then click make startup disk.

It may take a little while to finish.

## Step 4:

With the disk still  in the cd drive or usb plugged in, shut down your machine and start it back up. At the first loading screen hit ESC (may vary depending on machine) to access the boot menu. Once at this menu make sure you select the usb/cd and choose to try Ubuntu 14.04.

Step 5: In the trial version of ubuntu you will be logged into a temporary ubuntu session. Open up gparted, your computers hard drive should now be unmounted or at the least unmountable.

You should now be able to re-size your partition without any size restrictions, it may take a while to complete the task of resizing the partition depending on how much space you are trying to free up as well as how powerful your machine is.

**Oh and whatever you do**

**DO NOT UNPLUG THE USB OR EJECT THE CD, AND IF YOU CAN BACK UP YOUR MACHINE.**

If the process is interrupted at all it can damage your version of Ubuntu and for you to have to re-install Ubuntu. Like i had to because i  was rushing. If you don't know how to back up Ubuntu there should be plenty of resources online that you can google (Ex Search: How to backup Ubuntu 14.04)

Hope this helps and hope its not confusing in anyway. Good luck!